# AngularJS Filter; weird behaviour

Tags: angularjs, list, search, filter

Code:

```
<!--searchbar-->
<label class="item item-input" id="winzer-search3">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="">
</label>

<!--Spacer-->
<div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 24px;"></div>

<!--Wine List-->
<ion-list id="weine-list6" class="manual-list-fullwidth">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="wine in WinesOfEvent | filter:search" class="item-icon-right" id="weine-list-item28" ui-sref="winetastic.weinDetails" ng-click="setWine(wine)">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-wineglass"></i>{{wine.wineyear}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Everytime when I want to search after things I get a very weird list back.
Here are some examples
[image]

It doesn't search when I put only one number in the searchbar.

[image]

This should give me an empty list.
I can even search after letters and get results.

Whats wrong with my code?

WinesOfEvent looks like this:

```
[{"id":"eebedd09-a64c-43ac-80e8-2c8b54fdea1d","qualitylevel":"DAC","wineyear":2013,"region_description":" ","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"18e9da94-2795-46d2-a321-8620094a0be9","winetypename":"Cabernet"},{"id":"1b03e718-ee01-4297-9425-411c9716377c","qualitylevel":" ","wineyear":2012,"region_description":" ","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"ef2007cf-f776-484b-9829-883747d951b8","winetypename":"Steinberg"},{"id":"0a9bb7aa-f23c-487f-9848-9307e426fec6","qualitylevel":" ","wineyear":2014,"region_description":" ","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"c54fea22-8111-4cfc-bdd9-64298d6c7f54","winetypename":"Zweigelt"},{"id":"9318c4f2-650a-4209-8a7e-d0d49e1d3be3","qualitylevel":"","wineyear":2011,"region_description":"Diabas","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"637b193c-d57f-479a-86d1-4dcb5bce6de4","winetypename":"Blaufränkisch"},{"id":"c34a87f2-2ce6-4f9a-88e8-b7beec8f2245","qualitylevel":"DAC Reserve","wineyear":2013,"region_description":" ","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"637b193c-d57f-479a-86d1-4dcb5bce6de4","winetypename":"Blaufränkisch"},{"id":"8af68c20-9e53-4e78-8f64-3a59bd8d9ff0","qualitylevel":" ","wineyear":2012,"region_description":" Merlot","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"c54fea22-8111-4cfc-bdd9-64298d6c7f54","winetypename":"Zweigelt"},{"id":"bdc1442f-7abf-4fe8-99bf-0e3df8ecd0db","qualitylevel":"","wineyear":2012,"region_description":"Diabas","winzer_ID":"458a5050-5256-47b6-9986-397df3d26eb3","winetype_ID":"18e9da94-2795-46d2-a321-8620094a0be9","winetypename":"Cabernet"}]
```

Comment: Could you add the data of `WinesOfEvent` ?

Comment: Edited at my post. Please have a look

Comment: Think i got it. It looks through all attributes, not only wineyear.

Solution: filter:{wineyear: search}
Thanks! :)

Comment: Haha, glad to help ;)